# How to convert real to exact integer in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

How do I convert a value of the form `20.2` into something that `(random ...)` accepts?

I've tried these:

```
;; x defined by some earlier maths and of form 20.2

(random (round x))
(random (floor x))
```

But both return:

```
random: contract violation
expected: (or/c (integer-in 1 4294967087) pseudo-random-generator?)
given: 20.0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These also work, and according to the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmath..rkt%29._exact-round%29%29) they're just shorthands for your approach:

```
(random (exact-round x))
(random (exact-floor x))
```

Answer (score 5):

This article seems to answer the question for Scheme:
http://computer-programming-forum.com/40-scheme/674db7a1706960d5.htm

So with code like this I get the result I want:

```
(random (inexact->exact (round x)))
(random (inexact->exact (floor x)))
```

Is this the simplest way?

Comment: In racket, the [`exact-round`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmath..rkt%29._exact-round%29%29) and [`exact-floor`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmath..rkt%29._exact-floor%29%29) functions from racket/math do that.